# cannot boot ubuntu 13.10 with my usb, Can i change the kernal on my laptop to run it?

Tags: boot, kernel, 13.10, acer

Currently i am running 12.04 and looking for an upgrade to 13.10

I first tried a bootable 64bit usb and failed.
With the message saying

```
Kernel requires an x86-64 CPU but only detected an I686 CPU
Unable to boot please use a kernal appropriate for your CPU
```

then tried 32bit and same message came up.

Is this due to my laptop simply being to slow?

or can/should i change the kernal somehow?

Acer Aspire 5710z
Intel Pentium dual core processor, 1.73Ghz, 533 MHz FSB, 1 MB L2 cache.
2GB DDR2

```
sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for annette: 
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:d0300000-d037ffff ioport:5088(size=8) memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0400000-d043ffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0380000-d03fffff


lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
06:00.0 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
06:00.1 SD Host controller: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI SmartMedia / xD Card Reader Controller
06:00.2 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
06:00.3 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Secure Digital / MMC Card Reader Controller
```

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop is ok, just try to download the 32 bit version and reinstall. Remember to format the pendrive before.

Comment: Your thoughts were mine exactly and after I did the format and downloaded the 32bit, complete same procedure, and the same message came up

Kernel requires an x86-64 CPU but only detected an I686 CPU
Unable to boot please use a kernal appropriate for your CPU

Answer (score 1):

I think your computer can't run 64bit system. Try 32bit installation.

Comment: yes i can see now from the new sudo command that it is 32bit

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.10 seems to prior 64 Bits installation, so the links to download Ubuntu are 64 Bits by default.

Here is the link for the 32 Bits version : http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/